# Organize list in a table based on which button appears

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<thead>
    <tr class="header-bg">
         <th>Action</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Vendor</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Phone Number</th>
         <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody ng-repeat="entry in vm.emailList | orderBy: Name">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-danger relative fa fa-trash-o" ng-click="vm.deleteUser(entry)"> Delete</a>
            <a class="btn btn-success relative fa fa-users" ng-show="!entry.CAUserID" ng-click="vm.approveUser(entry)"> Approve</a>
            <a class="btn btn-info relative fa fa-pencil" ng-show="entry.CAUserID" ng-click="vm.editUser(entry)"> Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td>{{entry.UserName}}</td>
            <td>{{entry.UserID}}</td>
            <td>{{entry.CompanyName}}</td>
            <td>{{vm.convertPositionName(entry)}}</td>
            <td>{{entry.PhoneNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{entry.Comment}}</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have either an approve or edit button appearing right now based on whether or not there is the property CAUserID.

Right now my table is organizing based on the user's name.  But I want it to be organized first based on whether or not the approve or edit button appears and then by name.

Example:
If there are two users that have an approve button and their names are John and Sam.  And then there are three users that have an edit button and their names are Jen, Dan, and Tim.

This list would be organized like this: 
John 
Sam
Dan
Jen
Tim

Answer (score 1):

The condition for the button visibility is simple enough that you could possibly use it instead of the actual button visibility - try adding the `CAUserID` field to your `orderBy` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="entry in vm.emailList | orderBy: ['CAUserID', 'Name']">
```